# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

This is my python code of Bubble sort.It shows an error as decribed in the title.

```
def arrayinput(self):
        print ("Enter the elements")
        for i in range (0,n): //ERROR IS HERE
            b=input()
            arr.append(b)

def arraysorting(self):
    for i in range (1,n):
        for j in range (0,n-i):
            if ( arr[j]> arr[j+1]):
                temp=arr[j]
                arr[j]=arr[j+1]
                arr[j+1]=temp

def arraydisplay(self):
    print ("Sorted list is")
    print (arr)
```

Comment: what is `n`? I do not see it defined anywhere. I do not see any of the variables defined anywhere.

Comment: i have defined n but havent shown here...

Comment: Obviously, `n` is str. You would need those code as well for us to be able to tell you , what you are doing wrong. Please provide a [MCVE] .

Comment: You need to go back to basics if you do not understand the difference between a string and a number. Check out http://learnpython.org/en/Variables_and_Types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `b=input()` which means it is a string obtained from the keyboard. You want to re-cast it. Crudely, you can `b=int(input())`, but this is not a robust way of dealing with potential errors.

To do it in a bit more detail, you can try something like:

```
try:
   b=int(input())
except:
   print "You did not enter a valid integer"
```

edit:

On reading the comments, if `n` is a string, then you need to re-define that as an integer. I assume you have done something like:

```
print "How many times do you want to run?"
n=input()
```

Try instead:

```
n=int(input())
```

Comment: this works...but when i run the original code on terminal,it runs fine! what is the problem on eclipse?

Comment: Dont know, sorry, seldom use exclipse.